# Use jdeps for module which has multi-version implementation, but root module doesn't

Tags: java, java-9, jdeps

Not quite sure how to use jdeps to inspect module if current module has multi-version dependencies.

jdeps keep asking me provide `--multi-version 9` but other dependent modules is not multi-version.
How to properly use jdeps for such cases?

command:

```
jdeps  -cp .\..\..\..\modules --module-path .\..\..\..\modules  -s ws-gen.jar
```

Error: jaxb-api.jar is a multi-release jar file but --multi-release option is not set

command:

```
jdeps --multi-release 9 --module-path . -filter:package -s jaxb-api.jar
Error: bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar is not a multi-release jar file but --multi-release option is set
```

jdeps - earlier access from JDK11
command:

```
jdeps -version
11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bug in jdeps which is tracked by https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210502.

Answer (score 0):

This same bug in jdeps with Oracle-JDK: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8207162.